# Why is apt so dependent on individual Python versions?

Tags: apt, python, dependencies

We get a lot of questions here about people messing with Python versions and ruining their systems, most noticeably that apt fails to function properly. I am aware that [many Ubuntu packages require specific versions of Python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416772/ubuntu-and-its-dependancy-on-python) to function properly.

My question is: what makes a newer/different Python version incompatible with apt? Do these packages depend on language features that only exist in certain versions, or what version-specific Python features does apt depend on that makes it only work with one particular Python version?

Comment: This is not a q+a  kind of question :( I believe https://discourse.ubuntu.com/ might be better. I would not mind if Ubuntu was locked down to a specific python but installing another version would automatically envoke the ENVVARS method . So a setup where python version automatically co-exist.  The reason will be: python is easy to code. `apt` code totally be a C or C+ tool or even Perl. But python is a lot easier and is taught more in schools.

Comment: @Rinzwind my question is less about why a decision was made, and more about technically how it works. Like what makes a newer Python version incompatible with apt? Or is it just because it was decided that it shouldn't work, but technically it could?

Comment: @Rizwind although thanks for the Discourse link, I will be checking that out as well

Comment: Just as a side note, it's not only apt, it's the same case with a lot of other Ubuntu tools as well.

Comment: You can have different python versions but you can't have a different default python version and you need to keep the python versions that other packages depend on, so those packages do not break. Can you please provide another specific example? The example you provided mentions removing a version of Python and not installing a different version. If and when more than one version exist on the system, you simply have to call the alternate version specifically, like `python3.14` for example, and you can't simply run `python` or `python3` which are linked to the default versions.

Comment: Installing an alternative version of Python without knowing what you're doing can be a bit dangerous because you cannot replace, override, or uninstall the default versions without causing problems. So, if you would like to install an alternative version of Python on your system, this would be a good question to ask and completely on topic here on Askubuntu. There's also multiple different ways of installing. You can even install locally. You can also [use different a version for an isolated python virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1534343) which is one reason to use a venv.

Comment: There again with the virtual environment, you would explicitly call the alternate version of python by specifying the full path to the alternate version. This will tell the system that you want that instead of the default, so anything calling the default remains unchanged but the other version is still available to you.

Comment: `apt` is dependent on Python? Since when? It's a C++ program AFAIK. And we even had a question recently asking why Docker images of Ubuntu don't have Python on them, and those images definitely do have `apt`.

Comment: "*Do these packages depend on language features that only exist in certain versions*" This is hardly the reason since "moving" Ubuntu to Python3 ... "*or what version-specific Python features*" Mainly modules related differences between versions ... "*does apt depend*" Not APT itself but rather its [low level librarries/tools/backends](https://github.com/Debian/apt)

Comment: .. And the majority of Python related errors printed while using APT to e.g. install some packages is mostly generated by those packages install/configure scripts that ether use python directly or call system utilities that rely on Python ... That might cause a general misunderstanding that APT is depending on Python ... I think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it usually is specific language features that only exist in a certain Python version.

Depending on the issue, you will often get an error when an application like apt or more likely dpkg calls for something using the wrong syntax that doesn't exist in the newer version.

However [apt itself does not depend on python](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/apt) and the same is true for dpkg — but the packages that do depend on python often have pre and post install scripts that invoke python or python scripts.

For example, if you download the deb file for `software-properties-gtk`, extract that file, and then extract the `control.tar.xz` file, you will see a `prerm` script.

The script is an sh script but you can see that it also calls on python:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Automatically added by dh_python3:
if which py3clean >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    py3clean -p software-properties-gtk 
else
    dpkg -L software-properties-gtk | perl -ne 's,/([^/]*)\.py$,/__pycache__/\1.*, or next; unlink $_ or die $! foreach glob($_)'
    find /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ -type d -name __pycache__ -empty -print0 | xargs --null --no-run-if-empty rmdir
fi

# End automatically added section
```

So [`py3clean` is part of `python3-minimal`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=py3clean&mode=exactfilename&suite=kinetic&arch=any) and this script calls on `python3` in the shebang on the first line of the file as seen from the following commands:

```
which py3clean
```

and this should show `/usr/bin/py3clean` so:

```
head /usr/bin/py3clean
```

output:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# vim: et ts=4 sw=4

# Copyright © 2010-2012 Piotr Ożarowski <piotr@debian.org>
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
```

This is important because an actual file for `/usr/bin/python3` does not exist as you can see by the following command:

```
file /usr/bin/python3
```

On 20.04, this tells me that `/usr/bin/python3` is a symbolic link to python3.8 and `which python3.8` shows this file is `/usr/bin/python3.8`. Furthermore, `file /usr/bin/python3.8` confirms that this is the actual Python executable used for python3.

So the `software-properties-gtk` package is expecting that, if python3 is installed, that the version of python3 installed is python3.8.

The `py3clean` script may or may not work with a different python version, but there's often enough changes to python that there's probably at least one change somewhere in that script that would cause some type of error.

Even if not for this particular situation, you get the idea.

I guess to summarize, this isn't actually a problem with apt but more of a python problem because python scripts often use a generic shebang that expects a particular version of python when the shebang specifies `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python3` or even `/usr/bin/env python` or `/usr/bin/env python3` as none of these point to an actual file, they all point to a symbolic link that points to your default version of python installed on the system.

Since most packages are released for a particular version of Ubuntu, they all expect the default version of Python to be the same. Otherwise, each package would depend on a arbitrarily different Python version and we may end up with 3 or more versions of Python installed on the same system just to satisfy dependencies.

Typically, if you want or need a different version of Python installed, it's because you have a particular reason. And there's nothing stopping you from using a different version of Python for that reason, so long as you do not mess with the default version of python that other software use when they call on `python` or `python3`.

So if you do install an alternate version you will not have the convenience of calling that alternate version by `python` or `python3` as your default version — you will need to specify the version specifically by calling `python3.9`, for example, when you use it.

<sub>I guess I should add as a disclaimer for others reading this answer. **If you want to install a different version of python on your system, you should ask around to find the proper way to do it.** It is possible to have multiple versions of Python on one system but to avoid problems, you must not uninstall, change, or alter in any way the default version of Python. But I don't think going into more detail would be within the scope of this question.</sub>

Comment: one thing I'm unclear about is why a *newer* python version (which, as I understand, should have all the language features of an older one) still causes breaking changes. Although I've seen random other Python packages not work on newer versions, so I guess this wouldn't be any different, and it's more of a Python question

Comment: @Esther - the breaking issues generally fall into one of two categories 1) things that the author could get away with on the older version _but shouldn't have been doing_ and 2) things that have been deprecated for ages _that have been ignored for as long_. They are, of course, sometimes in a dependency of a given package rather than that package. Having had to maintain compatibility between python versions for several years with a little care it can be done. Of course this takes some effort from the maintainers but more from the user who need to **report** problems complete with test cases.

Comment: @Esther I think you're wrong to assume that the newer version has all the language features of the old one. From my experience, this is not the case. Python often changes and deprecates language features.

Comment: @Esther For example, [here's some stuff that was removed in 3.9 that would work in 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#removed) and also some other [language changes that function differently in 3.9 compared to 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#other-language-changes).